# Amplitude expansion close to bifurcation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, bifurcation

Consider a non-linear two-dimensional system of the form
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=F(x,y)\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=G(x,y)
\end{aligned}
$$
In the context of stability analysis, what is meant by an "amplitude (mode) expansion close to the bifurcation point"?

Any references are appreciated!

Comment: There is a parameter missing, bifurcation is about structural change of the phase portrait under parameter change. Then zoom in towards the bifurcation point, do a Taylor expansion and find the minimum amount of terms so that the reduced system is close to the full system.

Comment: @LutzLehmann do you have a reference?